# Fabric Fastlane Pilot Upload iTMSTransporter failure

Tags: ios, fastlane, google-fabric, fastlane-pilot

I have a problem running

```
fastlane pilot upload
```

I get this error:

> The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure

I checked online and everywhere they say to add

ENV['DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS'] = '-t DAV'
FASTLANE_ITUNES_TRANSPORTER_USE_SHELL_SCRIPT=1

But I get the same error anyway.
This is my FastFile

```
# More documentation about how to customize your build
# can be found here:
# https://docs.fastlane.tools
fastlane_version "1.109.0"

# This value helps us track success metrics for Fastfiles
# we automatically generate. Feel free to remove this line
# once you get things running smoothly!
generated_fastfile_id "MyNumber"

default_platform :ios

# Fastfile actions accept additional configuration, but
# don't worry, fastlane will prompt you for required
# info which you can add here later
lane :beta do
  # build your iOS app
  gym(
    # scheme: "MyScheme",
    export_method: "app-store"
  )

pilot(
    app_identifier "myAppIdentifier"
    apple_id "MyAppleId"  # Your Apple email address
    team_id "MyTeamId"     #  Developer Portal Team ID
    groups ""
    ENV['DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS'] = '-t DAV'
  FASTLANE_ITUNES_TRANSPORTER_USE_SHELL_SCRIPT=1
```

)

```
  pilot(ipa: "./MyIpaFile.ipa")

  # upload to Testflight
  pilot(skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true)

  # slack(
  #   slack_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/IDS"
  # )
end
```

I tried to put these 2 lines

ENV['DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS'] = '-t DAV' FASTLANE_ITUNES_TRANSPORTER_USE_SHELL_SCRIPT=1

also at the top of the file, or just one of those or none. Nothing.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the two environment variables outside (before) the call to pilot. You could, for example, have a before_all right before your beta lane.

You seem to be calling pilot 3 times. Why?

I would do like this:

```
# More documentation about how to customize your build
# can be found here:
# https://docs.fastlane.tools
fastlane_version "1.109.0"

# This value helps us track success metrics for Fastfiles
# we automatically generate. Feel free to remove this line
# once you get things running smoothly!
generated_fastfile_id "MyNumber"

default_platform :ios

# Fastfile actions accept additional configuration, but
# don't worry, fastlane will prompt you for required
# info which you can add here later

before_all do
  ENV['DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS'] = '-t DAV'
  ENV['FASTLANE_ITUNES_TRANSPORTER_USE_SHELL_SCRIPT'] = '1'
end

lane :beta do
  # build your iOS app
  gym(
    # scheme: "MyScheme",
    export_method: "app-store"
  )

  # upload to Testflight
  pilot(
    app_identifier: "myAppIdentifier",
    apple_id: "MyAppleId",  # Your Apple email address
    team_id: "MyTeamId",     #  Developer Portal Team ID
    groups: "",
    ipa: "./MyIpaFile.ipa",
    skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true
  )
end
```

Note that FASTLANE_ITUNES_TRANSPORTER_USE_SHELL_SCRIPT is set as an environment variable instead of as a Ruby variable and note that both that and DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS is set before any call to pilot()